# Jenkins phonegap error: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined

Tags: android, cordova, jenkins

I have been searching for solution for below issue now for more than 3 days. I discovered this happens when I add inappbrowser plugin, without it compiles successfully. Phonegap version is **3.3.0-0.19.6**

However it works on my local machine.

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project Dev Build/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined
    at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project Dev Build/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:361:71
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at handleInstall (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project Dev Build/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:360:40)
    at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project Dev Build/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:331:20
    at _fulfilled (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project Dev Build/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project Dev Build/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project Dev Build/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project Dev Build/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project Dev Build/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: @rkaartikeyan - I shifted to cordova from phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, and per the advice in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6008, I updated cordova `npm update -g cordova` to the latest version and then it worked.

EDIT: Ah I see you were using Phonegap, which is still on 3.3.  When they release the new version I'm sure `npm update -g  phonegap` would do the same thing.